# How do you copy using multi-select from Windows.Forms.OpenDialog in PowerShell using folder.copyHere() method?

Tags: powershell, user-interface, multi-select, robocopy

Nubie question ... but you've got to start somewhere.
In my powershell console, I call Windows.Forms.OpenDialog to open a GUI file picker and browse to a location on my system and multi-select files that I want to copy. I stash that list in a variable.
Next, I use browseForFolder to choose my destination folder path and stash that in a variable

I run folder.copyHere() to copy a file using the Windows default file xfer GUI.
One file at a time works.
I want to present my multi-selected filename list to folder.copyhere and have it process the list ...
Instead, I'm stuck in my ignorance using foreach($file in $list and sending that to folder.copyhere one at a time.  It's unpretty.

I tried turning my list of full-path file names into an array, and feeding folder.copyhere() the $vararray - but it wouldn't copy even the first file.  One at a time yes, but that's not what I want.
If I send my list to robocopy, it processes each item in order, like a champ.
But I have GUI users and they want the GUI.  Ideas on how to get folder.copyhere() to accept an array of names to process?

Comment: folder.CopyHere() only accepts a file name, folder item, or list of folder items. It does not accept a list of file names. There is nothing wrong with using your own loop. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks EBGreen for the clarity.  My issue with feeding it a loop is that if I cancel the current file in the loop - it simply picks up with the next file.  If I multi-select in file explorer and drag and drop that collection to another folder, it simply processes the collection.  I was hoping that 'feature' was exposed by folder.copyhere() ...  I appreciate the education.

Comment: The Shell folder Object does not have exposed event hooks. I've never needed to do what you are trying but I think I would look at the .Net [FolderBrowserDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) object. It at least exposes event hooks.